# How do I determine if a set of vectors span?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have an assignment where I should proof that three matrices span $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 1}$. Here is the matrices:

$$ b_1=\pmatrix{1\\ 1\\ 1\\} b_2=\pmatrix{0\\1\\1\\} b_3=\pmatrix{0\\-1\\1}$$

For this I have to determine this two things:

$$c_1\pmatrix{1\\ 1\\ 1\\} +c_2\pmatrix{0\\1\\1\\} +c_3\pmatrix{0\\-1\\1} = \pmatrix{0\\0\\0\\}$$

And:

$$c_1\pmatrix{1\\ 1\\ 1\\} +c_2\pmatrix{0\\1\\1\\} +c_3\pmatrix{0\\-1\\1} = \pmatrix{a\\b\\c\\}$$

So if I do some matrix algebra I get this:

$$\pmatrix{c_1\\c_1+c_2-c_3\\c_1+c_2+c_3\\}=\pmatrix{0\\0\\0\\}$$

And:

$$\pmatrix{c_1\\c_1+c_2-c_3\\c_1+c_2+c_3\\}=\pmatrix{a\\b\\c\\}$$

And then what? Am I done now? In case of that, how could this not be true?

Comment: If you have learnt row reduction, how about using that to reduce the $3 \times 3$ matrix consisting of these three matrices as row vectors to the identity matrix

Comment: Could I just create a 3x3 matrix using b1,b2 and b3 as colums? If I could do that then I know that if the determinant is not equal to zero, then this is a basis (which means that it also span). Could I do that?

Comment: ofcourse yes. When you put them as columns and get a non zero determinant, it actually implies that the columns span $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrices space is 3 dimensional, so these three vectors span the space iff they are linearly independent.
An easy way to check linear independence in the case, is to create a $3 \times 3$ matrix with the three vectors as rows (or columns), and calculate the determinant. If it differs from 0, the matrix is rank $3$, and the vectors are linearly independent. If It is $0$ then the rank is smaller than $3$ and they are not linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to determine the rank of the matrix
$$\pmatrix{1 \ \ \ \ 0 \ \ \ \ 0 \\ 1 \ \  \ 1 \  \ -1\\ 1\ \ \ \ 1 \ \ \ \ 1\\} $$
If the rank of this matrix is 3, then this set of vectos span $\mathbb{R}^3.$

Comment: i think your first sentence is a bit mixed up

Comment: yes your are right thank you i will edit it

Answer (score 0):

I will mark the matrices (they are really vectors) in your case with $A_1$, $A_2$ and $A_3$.

Actually, you must prove these two things:

1. For any three scalars $c_1, c_2, c_3$ for which $c_1A_1 + c_2 A_2 + c_3 A_3 = 0$, it follows that $c_1=c_2=c_3=0$.
2. For any vector $v=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$, there exist such scalars $c_1, c_2, c_3$ that $c_1A_1 + c_2 A_2 + c_3 A_3 = v$

You have correctly calculated what $c_1A_1 + c_2 A_2 + c_3 A_3 = 0$ is, but can you prove the two points I noted above? That is where you have to actually do some deductions.